# A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "setCredentials()" can return null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

Why is Sonar flagging up this as a possible NullPointerException?

```
public void credentialSetter(@Headers Map<String, Object> headersMap) {

    SoapHeader uName = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, USERNAMETOKEN), 
            setCredentials(USERNAMETOKEN, this.username).getDocumentElement());

    SoapHeader pTxt = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, P), 
            setCredentials(P, this.pas).getDocumentElement());
```

It flats up at "setCredentials" both times, I've tried surrounding it with an if statement to check if it's not null, also tried to check if it's null in the actual method just to cover all basis.

```
private Document setCredentials(String credential, String value) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context;
    try {
        if (null != credential && null != value) {
            context = JAXBContext.newInstance(value.getClass());
            QName qName = new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, credential);
            JAXBElement<String> root = new JAXBElement<>(qName, String.class, value);
            context.createMarshaller().marshal(root, writer);
            return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                    .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(writer.toString())));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Error converting {} to XML {}", credential, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I guess that it is because setCredentials can `return null`

Comment: @DamCx I get that but it will (hopefully) never return null and the return statement is just there to complete the method, what could I try instead of that?

Comment: @DamCx In case of an exception or credential or value is null you return null. What you cando depends on what should be happening if you get an exception here:  Throw a runtime exception maybe an option.

Comment: I also recommand to not catch the base class of exception. Only catch checked exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of `setCredentials()` returns null so there is a possibility that the two following lines throw a `NullPointerException`. Wrapping your logic in a null-check doesn't really help here because there is still a possibility it will return `null`

```
SoapHeader uName = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, USERNAMETOKEN), 
        setCredentials(USERNAMETOKEN, this.username).getDocumentElement());

SoapHeader pTxt = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, P), 
        setCredentials(P, this.pas).getDocumentElement());
```

A solution would be to use the following

```
SoapHeader uName;
Document document = setCredentials(USERNAMETOKEN, this.username);
if (document != null) {
    uName = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, USERNAMETOKEN), 
            document.getDocumentElement());
} else {
    // whatever you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `getDocumentElement()` on `setCredentials's` returning value, that can be `null`. If it would be the case, you would got an exception. That's the reason why Sonar is warning you.

OK, you have enclosing the main logic of `setCredentials` with a try-catch, but you still returning `null` in case of errors.

Just as a general idea, you could do something like these:

```
Document credentials = setCredentials(USERNAMETOKEN, this.username);
if (null != credentials){
    SoapHeader uName = new SoapHeader(new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, USERNAMETOKEN), 
            credentials.getDocumentElement());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setCredentials()` method can return null : `return null;`

Sonar is detecting this + the fact that you use the returned object to `.getDocumentElement()`, which would infer in a NPE since it's a null reference.

If you want to override this (wouldn't recommend doing so) return a new instance of Document instead of null (assuming the method newInstance() actually returns a new instance):

```
private Document setCredentials(String credential, String value) {
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext context;
try {
    if (null != credential && null != value) {
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(value.getClass());
        QName qName = new QName(NAMESPACE_URL, credential);
        JAXBElement<String> root = new JAXBElement<>(qName, String.class, value);
        context.createMarshaller().marshal(root, writer);
        return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(writer.toString())));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Error converting {} to XML {}", credential, e);
}
return DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

}